# Getting email from google auth using vue, pinia, supabase

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, supabase, pinia

wanting to add google auth to my vue app using supabase. How can i insert the users email from there google account into my users table once they sign up? my code to signup with email is below.

```
const handleSignup = async (credentials) => {
const { email, password, name } = credentials;

if(password.length < 6){
console.log("password way too short")
return errorMessageSignUp.value = "Password length is too short"
}

if(!validateEmail(email)){
    return errorMessageSignUp.value = "Email is invalid"
}

loading.value = true

const {error} = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email,
    password,
  })
  if(error){
    loading.value = false
    return errorMessageSignUp.value = error.message
  }

await supabase.from("users").insert({
    email,
    name
  })

  const { data: newUser } = await supabase
  .from("users")
  .select()
  .eq('email', email)
  .single()

  user.value = {
    email: newUser.email,
    name: newUser.name
  }


loading.value = false
}
```

since the above takes in the email and password field and inserts it into the users table, im wanting to do the same when a user signups with google auth.

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
provider: 'google',
})
}

// not sure on how to get email from google sign in/sign up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the email address on the front end, which could fail if the network is lost right after signing up, you can use [database triggers](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data#using-triggers) to copy the data in the background when users sign up. This is more fail-tolerant and is the recommended way to implement such features in Supabase.

```sql
-- inserts a row into public.users
create function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
security definer set search_path = public
as $$
begin
  insert into public.profiles (id, email)
  values (new.id, new.email);
  return new;
end;
$$;

-- trigger the function every time a user is created
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

You can read more on the official guide [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data#using-triggers).